Get the raw data (type 0x02) from Fingertip SpO2 sensor KS-CM01
Get the raw data (type 0x02) from Fingertip SpO2 sensor KS-CM01
I have questions about getting the raw data from KS-CM01 (a Fingertip SpO2 sensor). I have sent the "aa 55 50 03 02 02 c5" to the KS-CM01 through serial communication. Unfortunately, I still got the type 0x01 data, which was normalized. Has anyone used this sensor could help me? Thanks! Here is some code.
# send command to the KS-CM01

command = "aa5550030202c5"

command_byte = bytes.fromhex(command)
ser.write(command_byte)
sleep(5)

data = ser.read_all().hex()
if command in data:
    print("Setup Successful! \n")
else:
    print("Setup failed! \n")

# get data from it

text = ""

while True:

    data = ser.read_all()  # str
        
    if data == b'':
        continue

    text = text + data.hex()

    text_split = text.split("aa55")
    num_text = len(text_split)

    if num_text < 2:
        continue

    else:
        text = text_split[num_text-1]

        for i in range(num_text-1):
                
            response_ = text_split[i]
                
            if response_ == "":
                continue
                
            response_ = "aa55"+response_

            response_ = re.findall(r'.{2}', response_)
            print(response_)

I hope I could get the raw (0x02) data.
